# Induction on a well-founded order in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I have to prove a property of this form:

```
lemma 
  assumes "set E ⊆ set E'" "⊢ E' ok"
  shows "set (cv T E b) ⊆ set (cv T E' b)"
```

I want to prove it using something like:

```
proof(induction "(size T, length E)" 
        arbitrary: E T rule: less_induct)
```

meaning that the induction hypothesis should give me the property for all pairs T, E such that in the lexicographic order:

`(size T, length E)`

is smaller.

So far I only got the error message:

```
exception THM 0 raised (line 760 of "drule.ML"):
  infer_instantiate_types: type ?'a of variable ?a
  cannot be unified with type nat × nat of term x__
  (⋀x. (⋀y. y < x ⟹ ?P y) ⟹ ?P x) ⟹ ?P ?a
```

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60531192/isabelle-code-generation-and-linear-order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the typeclass instance for the ordering on pairs is not imported by default. You can import `"HOL-Library.Product_Lexorder"` to get the normal lexicographical ordering on pairs.

Alternatively you can use the rule `wf_induct` and provide your own well-founded relation.

Comment: as you say , for the future, something like (induction _ "(length E, size T)"
        arbitrary: E T E' rule: wf_induct[OF wf_lex_prod[OF wf_less_than wf_less_than]]) can also work